# yii2 load dropdown multiple selected items

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii2

I have a form where I have a dropdown list with multiple selection.

```
$items = ArrayHelper::map(Categories::find()->orderBy('name')->all(), 'id', 'name');

echo $form
    ->field($cats, 'fk_cat_id')
    ->dropDownList(
        $items, 
        ['prompt' => 'Select category', 'multiple' => 'multiple']
    )
    ->label('Category')
```

In controller, when I pass the model to the view, the category model is found like this:

```
$cats = Categories::find()->where(['fk_model_id' => $id])->one();
```

In this case, everything works and one item has been selected that has been assigned to the model. However if I want to autoselect all values like this:

```
$cats = Categories::find()->where(['fk_model_id' => $id])->all();
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Call to a member function formName() on a non-object
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

With one() you get a model but with all() you get an array of models (ActiveQuery), you have to fill the dropDown in your view or in controller as another variable. For example, in your view try:

```
$cats = ArrayHelper::map(Categories::find()->orderBy('name')->all();

$form->field($model, 'fk_cat_id')->dropDownList($cats, 'fk_cat_id', 'name'));
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for feedback! However, in this case I get the following error: `array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a parenthesis: `map(Categories::find()->orderBy('name')->all())`

Comment: That doesn't prevent the error. Assigning the `fk_cat_id`in `dropDownList()`seems to throw the error. I don't get why though...

Comment: It seems like the only way to go is to get the ID's of selected values in the controller, pass them to the view and then use BaseHtml to assign the default selected options.

Comment: In the `dropDownList()` the param should be the **id** field of Categories model, not `fk_cat_id`. Try it again.

Comment: The `fk_cat_id` is actually a field of the same table indicating the parent of the category. I've tried replacing it with just `id`, but no luck. I still get the `Argument #2 is not an array` error.

Comment: Can you post the `Categories` model?

Comment: `$form->field($model, 'fk_cat_id')->dropDownList($cats, 'cat_id', 'name'));` didn't work, right?

Comment: No. I truly believe I should go with non-active dropdown. Once because then I could retrieve a list of selected items separately from database and secondly, I'd like to display the dropdown hierarchically, which isn't happening now for more than 3 level children. Thank you for support anyway!